# Copy all files in folder to another folder appending a . to the file name and rename it back to original file name

Tags: linux, centos, files, rename, file-copy

after searching and trying various way I couldn't get it work.

I need to copy lots of files (more than 100 thousand files) to another folder with dot appended to the start of the file name.

Example:

- `/foo/bar/filename1.txt` to `/foo2/bar/.filename1.txt`
- and then rename it back to original name `/foo2/bar/filename.txt`

Why I need to do this is because I have an application that will keep scanning `/foo2/bar` folder and ignore those file with a dot in front of the file name so that it will not process those file that are copying half way. This mainly because the 2 folder can be in 2 different network drive or some mounted devices.

And i cannot simply use mv or cp because I have some folder that has too many files and it will simply throw argument list too long error thus I have been trying to use find command but to no avail.

Trying out with different command:

```
find /foo/bar/ -type f -exec cp -t /foo2/bar {} +
```

and

```
find /foo/bar/ -type f -exec mv {} /foo2/bar/.{} \;
```

I know the above command won't do what I wanted that is along the line of what i've tired.

Appreciate anyone that can help...

Comment: why not use `mkdir /foo2; cp -a /foo/bar /foo2`? The command `cp -a` copies all files recursively.

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -a -T tmpdir /foo/bar/ /foo2/bar
```

(Note that the `/` at the end of `/foo/bar/` is significant.)

The `rsync` utility will write files in `tmpdir` before moving these to the correct name under `/foo2/bar`.  You could, for example, use a hidden directory under `/foo2/bar` to store the in-transit files:

```
mkdir -p /foo2/bar/.tmp
rsync -a -T /foo2/bar/.tmp /foo/bar/ /foo2/bar
```

See also the `rsync` manual, especially the section about the `-T` option.

The above command will copy `/foo/bar` recursively to `/foo2/bar`.  To disable the recursiveness, use `rsync -a --no-recursive ...` (the `-a` option enables recursion as well as syncing of file metadata, and `--no-recursion` turns off only the recursion aspect of `-a`).

Comment: I forgot to mention that my application will scan /foo2/bar and its sub folder thus I think if those transferring file are place temporary in .tmp folder it will get process... thus it will not work using this rsync